# C#, Generic Lists and Inheritance

Tags: c#, list, generics, inheritance

I have a class called Foo that defines a list of objects of type A:

```
class Foo {
    List<A> Items = new List<A>();
}
```

I have a class called Bar that can save and load lists of objects of type B:

```
class Bar {
    void Save(List<B> ComplexItems);
    List<B> Load();
}
```

B is a subclass of A. Foo, Bar, A and B are in a library and the user can create children of any of the classes.

What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
Foo MyFoo = new Foo();
Bar MyBar = new Bar();

MyFoo.Items = MyBar.Load();
MyBar.Save(MyFoo.Items);
```

Obviously this won't work. Is there a clever way to do this that avoids creating intermediate lists?

thanks, Andy

Comment: what does "B is a child of A" mean? In the code listing you've given, A and B are type parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by "child"? Do you mean "derived class"?

Comment: ok, but in your example, A and B are the type parameters used in the definitions of types Foo and Bar. This is quite confusing.

Comment: OK. Consider A = Shape and B = Circle. I want to load a list of circles into a list of shapes and save a list of shapes that I know are all circles. Circle is derived from Shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .NET 4.0 and `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>` (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx), otherwise make `Save` generic on `T` (the list item type) as well.

Comment: I see that IEnumerable is what I need but sadly I can't use .NET 4.0. Bah!

Comment: Then I'd make class Bar generic: `class Bar<T> where T : A {     void Save(List<T> ComplexItems);     List<T> Load(); }` and instantiate it with Bar<B>.  Alternatively make just the methods themselves generic (may be easier especially with type inference): `void Save<T>(List<T> ComplexItems) where T : A;     List<T> Load<T>(); where T : A } `

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your save function to take an IEnumerable then you can :

```
void Save(IEnumerable<B> ComplexItems);
Save(MyFoo.Items.Cast<B>());
```

Comment: Thanks. What about the Load function?